# Глюк анимации при наведении. Картинка как бы раздваевается

Tags: html, css, css3, html5, css-animation

Сталкивался кто с таким? При наведении картинка должнай уйти вправо  и вверх и у её оверлея меняется прозрачность, но периодически картинка как бы раздваивается при наведении. И это только в мозилле в хроме и опере нормально работает. 
Вот сам глюк на стоп кадре, картинка сместилась с появился оверлэй, но она как сзади.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Через секунду отрисовывается правильно. 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот наглядно 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

HTML ---

```
<div class="storyImg">
    <a class="imgItem" href="#"><img src="img/aboutUs/1.jpg" alt=""><span><i class="fas fa-user-friends"></i><br>super team</span> </a>
    <a class="imgItem" href="#"><img src="img/aboutUs/2.jpg" alt=""><span><i class="far fa-tachometer-fast"></i><br>Swift delivery</span></a>
    <a class="imgItem" href="#"><img src="img/aboutUs/3.jpg" alt=""><span><i class="fas fa-gavel"></i><br>high quality</span></a>
</div>
```

CSS ---

```
.storyImg{
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content:center;
    margin-bottom: 110px;
    .imgItem{
            margin: 20px 10px 0 10px;
            position: relative;
            text-decoration: none;
            color: #fff;
            transition: all .3s;
            span{
                text-transform: uppercase;
                font-size: 16px;
                font-weight: bold;
                position: absolute;
                top: -20%;
                left: 50%;
                margin-left: -17%;
                text-align: center;
                width: 34%;
                display: none;
                transition: all .5s;
                opacity: 0;
                display: block;
                z-index: 9999;
            } 
    }
    .imgItem:after{
        content: '';
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        background-color: #000;
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        opacity: 0;
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient( 90deg, rgb(252,227,138) 0%, rgb(243,129,129) 100%);
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient( 90deg, rgb(252,227,138) 0%, rgb(243,129,129) 100%);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient( 90deg, rgb(252,227,138) 0%, rgb(243,129,129) 100%);
    }


    .imgItem:hover{
    box-shadow: 7px 7px 0px 0 $c_blue;
    transform: translate(-7px, -7px);
     span{
            opacity: 1;
            top: 40%;
    }
    &:after{
        opacity:0.9;
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Причесал" CSS... Проблемы не наблюдаю:

```css
.storyImg {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-bottom: 110px;
}

.imgItem {
  position: relative;
  height: 250px;
  margin: 20px 10px 0 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: all .4s;
}
.imgItem:hover {
  box-shadow: 7px 7px 0 0 #96DFD2;
  transform: translate(-7px, -7px);
}

.imgItem span {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  display: block;
  width: 34%;
  top: -20%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -17%;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-shadow: 0px 1px 1px black;
  opacity: 0.0;
  transition: all 0.6s;
}
.imgItem:hover span {
  opacity: 1.0;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.imgItem:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  background-color: #000;
  opacity: 0.0;
  background-image: linear-gradient( 90deg, rgb(252, 227, 138) 0%, rgb(243, 129, 129) 100%);
  transition: opacity .2s;
}
.imgItem:hover:after {
  opacity: 0.9;
}

/* Для отображения картинок */
img { object-fit: none; width: 380px; height: 250px; }
img[alt='img1'] { object-position: -13px -15px; }
img[alt='img2'] { object-position: -413px -15px; }
img[alt='img3'] { object-position: -813px -15px; }
```

```html
<div class="storyImg">
  <a class="imgItem" href="#"><img src="//i.stack.imgur.com/GcR9S.jpg" alt="img1"><span><i class="fas fa-user-friends"></i>super team</span></a>
  <a class="imgItem" href="#"><img src="//i.stack.imgur.com/GcR9S.jpg" alt="img2"><span><i class="far fa-tachometer-fast"></i>Swift delivery</span></a>
  <a class="imgItem" href="#"><img src="//i.stack.imgur.com/GcR9S.jpg" alt="img3"><span><i class="fas fa-gavel"></i>high quality</span></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Как ни странно, теперь и  меня нет этого бага. Благодарю.

Comment: @Dio у Вас два разных свойства `display` в одном правиле стояли. Как только я к нормальному CSS привёл, после всяких препроцессоров, то всё сразу стало очевидно))

Comment: Даже на планшете работает..

Comment: @UbuntuUser это хорошо) А то бывает, что всё правильно сделаешь и всё работает, а тебя минусят... Оказывается, просто в другом браузере открыли. Тем не менее, я против захламления ответа префиксами (благо, ситуация улучшается с поддержкой) - кому надо, тот добавит - главное, решение найдено.

Answer (score 0):

Картинка не раздваевается, а смещается немного. У вас стоит `transform` у картинки. Уберите его и ничего прыгать не будет.

```
.imgItem:hover {
    transform: translate(-7px, -7px);
}
```

Comment: нет смещение так и задумано, просто периодически глюк проскакивает, что картинка смещается, появляется оверлэй, но тоже время как бы она остаётся на месте, добавил скрин самого глюка вверху

Comment: @Dio хм по гифкам всеравно не вижу дублирования, можете залить куда-нибудь полностью с картинками?

Comment: @RogatnevNikita на средней картинке проявляется отчётливо.

Comment: @Dio копайте в сторону z-index. Такое впечатление, что его изменение срабатывает раньше всех остальных трансформаций.

Comment: исходник https://yadi.sk/d/pI-jfLwUsny3Lw   что интересно иногда нормально срабатывает анимация, а иногда так и ток в мозиле так

Comment: Теперь понял о чем вы, в каком браузере и ОС можно воспроизвести, на маке во всех все ок

Comment: z-index вроде бы не изменяется, глюк только в мозиле, ОС Windows